# Building an accordion with a Matrix field

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to build an accordion in my matrix field (that also holds entries for a slideshow, button, image, etc).

Im having trouble with getting each entry to go inside **< div id="accordion">< /div>** and not repeat this accordion div over and over.

```
{% elseif block.type == "sectionaccordion" %}

    <div id="accordion">
      {% for block in entry.sectionaccordion %}
        <div class="accordiontitle">{{ block.accordionTitle }}</div>
        <div class="accordion-content default">
          {{ block.accordionText }}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

With this setup, I keep getting *Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "sectionaccordion".*

[image]

Comment: Is ``entry.sectionaccordion`` another matrix field or a block inside another matrix? You can't do matrix within a matrix inside Craft...

Comment: Nope its just a block type in my matrix. Updated with an image of my matrix settings.

Answer (score 3):

The error has to do with the line `{% for block in entry.sectionaccordion %}` because it's looking for a field in your entry called `sectionaccordion` but `sectionaccordion` is not a field; it's a block *inside* a field (your matrix field).  So the error is basically saying "there is no field called 'sectionaccordion' for this entry".

You also don't want to use a `for` loop here because there's nothing to loop through.  You're already looping through matrix blocks created in this matrix field, and your code is saying "if the block is of type `sectionaccordion`, print the contents of it."  The contents of that block won't be another loop; it'll only be 1 Accordion Title and 1 Accordion Text field.

Lastly, by saying `{% elseif block.type == "sectionaccordion" %}`, you are eliminating the chance to display a slideshow since that is a different block type, one not called `sectionaccordion`.  If you want a slideshow inside your accordion block type, then you need to create a 3rd field for it inside `sectionaccordion` and just recreate whatever you did in the `sectionslideshow` block type.

Comment: Thanks, I think i realized what I was trying to do wont work with your second paragraph, since it would just be 1 accordian title and field.

So how would someone compile a UL list using a matrix field? Thats basically what im trying to do.

Comment: You'd probably need to just create a matrix field for this called `accordion` or whatever.  In that Matrix field, you'd only have one block type, and in that type you'd have the title and text fields.

Comment: But thats not an option if you have a matrix field for filling up content on a page, and allowing the client to insert photos, text, buttons, captions etc. I want the accordian, or even a simple list, to be one of those options in the matrix field, so they can put it an any spot in their page.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new option in your page matrix (the one with lots of options for photos, text etc) - an entries field that links to a new section called 'faqs'.

That 'faqs' section has one matrix in it - 'faqs', with two fields: 'faqTitle' and 'faqAnswer'.

The code would be something like:
*(you'd need to wrap it in your faq code, and assuming the entries field is in a matrix)*

```
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries.section('faqs').relatedTo(block) %}
{% for rel in relatedEntries %}
{% set relBlocks = rel.faqs.all() %}
{% for relBlock in relBlocks %}
{{ relBlock.faqTitle }}
{{ relBlock.faqAnswer }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```